# Suggestions for creating a Dynamic Bar Chart using SiIgnalR, Net Core & C#

Tags: dynamic, charts, signalr

I think I have become blinded by too much information and need some advice from the community if possible please.

The background is that I have a long running ETL process that consists of numerous services that are all managed via Kafka messaging. Because it is long running I need to come up with some real time visual that can give an indication of what is going on at any given time. I have already completed the code that picks up on the Kafka messages and uses SignalR to send notifications to a web page that currently show a textual representation of what is going on.

So, background over, I am only asking for help with regards to visualization libraries that would help me to create something like a Bar Chart that can be updated in real-time dynamically, i.e. be able to add items to the 'X' access as they start to be processed, update each 'X' access item with counts of items processed and errors logged and remove items from the 'X' axis when they have completed. So I would like this bar chart to something that appears to scroll along from left to right OR right to left as items are added and removed.

I have found so many different libraries that would produce the charts nicely BUT they seem to depend on relatively static data or call backs to reload any new data. I need something that works with SignalR so everything is animated and in as real-time as possible.

I am currently just using a very basic Net Core C# MVC web app with a single view and plain JS on the page. Can anybody suggest any pointers to a client side library that would fit the bill or any examples that they know of in any other format that I could make fit my needs?

This is the sort of thing that I am looking for
[Real-time Chart](https://img.techbrij.com/1030/html5-chart-push-webapi.Gif) - the only difference is that each 'Bar' will be a process and value of the 'Bar' will be incremently until a 'completed' message is received and then the 'Bar' will be removed.

As always any help would be greatly appreciated

**Edit:**

I may not have explained what I am trying to do very well so to clarify I need something that can update existing data in the graph. Just to clarify a little more on what I have stated above. A message is sent from the server stating a service has started, this service is then added to the bar chart, there can be multiple start messages for different services as they all run asynchronously. Now as data is processed is by each service a message is sent stating that the process succeeded or failed, this should then increment the value of the bar for the applicable service. Once a service has completed a finished message is sent and the applicable service bar is removed from the bar chart. As each service is added to the bar chart everything that is currently there shuffles up. I hope that is clearer?

Comment: You can have a look at this SignalR demo that uses chart.js to update in real-time the data that is coming through SignalR: https://github.com/Kiril1512/SignalRDemo

Comment: Thank you, I have looked at this and and it is close but I need something that can update existing data in the graph instead of loading all the data each time.

Comment: chartjs.org has capability for this through updates - https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html or through a plugin  that streams live data - https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-streaming/master/samples/charts/bar-horizontal.html

Comment: @Reggie my demo uses chart.js and it's the right thing to use for what you want...

Answer (score -1):

I finally found Chart.js can do exactly what I need. Thank you Frank M, I found Chart.js before I saw your post but thank you for posting the links.

[Vertical Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/vertical.html)